# Is there an addition formula for $ f(z) = \exp(z) + \sin(z) $?

Tags: arithmetic, exponential-function, functional-equations

I know $\exp(z) , \sin(z) , \sin^2(z) , z \exp(z) , \sinh(z) , \exp(z) \sin(z) $ all have addition formulas.

I'm still confused about addition formulas.

It seems hard to tell if a function has an addition formula or not.

Perhaps related : [About the addition formula $f(x+y) = f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444517/about-the-addition-formula-fxy-fxgyfygx)

[Analytic solutions to $f(x+y) +h(x+y)= f(x)(g(y)+h(y)) + g(x)(f(y)+h(y)) + h(x)(f(y)+g(y))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608341/analytic-solutions-to-fxy-hxy-fxgyhy-gxfyhy-hx)

[Visual proof of the addition formula for $\sin^2(a+b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443411/visual-proof-of-the-addition-formula-for-sin2ab)

Second question :

Does every function with an addition formula grow exponentially fast ?

Comment: For your second question, it depends on how rigidly you define an addition formula; $f(x)=0$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ (amongst other possible formulae). The answer is probably no, though.

Comment: @πr8 Using that addition formula, $f(x)=ax$ also works and does not grow exponentially.

Comment: It is hard, in general, to determine if a function has an addition formula (or satisfies any functional relationship).

Comment: It is a famous, though unfashionable, theorem of Weierstrass that any meromorphic function with an algebraic addition theorem (i.e. $G(f(u),f(v),f(u+v))=0$ for a polynomial in 3 variables $G$) if and only if it is one of the following: 1) a rational function of $z$, 2) a rational function of $e^{\lambda z}$ for some $\lambda$, or 3) an elliptic function. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6471) §2 for a proof, although the author's style is quite enthusiastic in places.

Comment: For the second part, note that, for example, $f(x)=x^2$ has the addition formula $(f(a+b)-f(a)-f(b))^2=4f(a)f(b)$, and does not grow exponentially.